# Javascript graphics library using percents

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript graphics library that allows you to use percents rather than pixels? I'm building a game based on small images (16 x 16) so if the library also has tools for loading a large number of images and tools to display them that would be great but if not that is ok also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Straightforward answer:**

Converting from pixels to percents is simple, just divide your percent value by 100 and then multiply by the width/height of your canvas:

```
x = percentX / 100 * width;
y = percentY / 100 * height;
```

**WebGL:**

If you need a complete graphics API, then you should look at WebGL: It's an OpenGLES 2.0 binding for Javascript, so everything available in OpenGLES 2.0 is available in WebGL.

Look at the MDN's tutorial to get started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Getting_started_with_WebGL

If you need others OpenGL tutorial, here are somes great ones:

- [opengl-tutorial.com](http://opengl-tutorial.com)
- [learnopengl.com](http://learnopengl.com)
- [tomdalling.com/blog/category/modern-opengl](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/category/modern-opengl/)